solana.rpc.core.RPCException: RpcCustomErrorFieldless.TransactionSignatureVerificationFailure
py code:
import asyncio
import base64
import base58
from solana.rpc.async_api import AsyncClient
from jupiter_python_sdk.jupiter import Jupiter
from solders import solders
from solders.keypair import Keypair

private_key_base58 = "3CyxYns1XUd5m9DDfivXzGNvcK8Lxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
input_mint = 'EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v'  #  usdc
output_mint = '3bRTivrVsitbmCTGtqwp7hxXPsybkjn4XLNtPsHqa3zR'  #  like
amount = 1000000


async def execute_swap():
    private_key_bytes = base58.b58decode(private_key_base58)
    keypair = Keypair.from_bytes(private_key_bytes)
    async_client = AsyncClient("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")
    
    jupiter = Jupiter(async_client=async_client, keypair=keypair)
    transaction_data = await jupiter.swap(
        input_mint=input_mint,
        output_mint=output_mint,
        amount=amount,
        slippage_bps=50
    )

    tx = solders.transaction.VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(transaction_data))
    result = await async_client.send_transaction(tx)

    # tx = VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(transaction_data))
    # result = await async_client.send_transaction(tx, keypair)
    
    await async_client.close()
    print(f"Transaction sent: {result}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(execute_swap())


